# How can I add from to comparison to a SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, momentjs

So I ran into an issue where I was passing a from-to set of parameters from C# into a `SqlCommand`. My test scenario involved the following dates

- from: Aug 30 2016
- to: Aug 31 2016

However, the results are including data from Sept 1 2016.

Using SQL Server profiler I can see that the date going into the SQL query is '2016-09-01 00:00:00' instead of 2016-08-31 23:59:59.

Here is the relevant C# snippet

```
if (request.DateStart != DateTime.MinValue) 
   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dateStart", request.DateStart));

if (request.DateEnd != DateTime.MinValue) 
   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dateEnd", request.DateEnd));
```

What would be causing C# to change the date it is sending to SQL?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that on the front end I was using moment(to).endOf('day') to send the end of day to the DateEnd paramater on the API.  The problem is that that ends up being a date of '2016-08-31 23:59:59:9990'.  This just happens to be greater precision than SQL's datetime type so c# helpfully rounds the date value to '2016-09-01 00:00:00'.

I've changed the front end code to the following and that fixed the problem. In this case it turns out that there is such a thing as too much precision.

```
 moment(filter.dateEnd).add(1, 'day').add(-1, 'second')
```

Comment: If it create a time of "59:59:59:9990", then that's just invalid since there are only 24 hours in a day (not 60).

Comment: You have that same issue in your question.